# Set value of specific cell in Xceed DataGrid based on index

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed-datagrid

I just started using the Xceed DataGrid and i'm attempting to set the value of a cell to a string.

The Xceed DataGrid seems to have a Columns property, but it seems there is no way to get the cells, in the order they appear in the datagrid, based on an index.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're supposed to data bind a collection to the `ItemsSource` property and then you'll have the collection of items (that represent the rows in the `DataGrid`) which you can update in any way you see fit.

Comment: @Sheridan This does not work for me unfortunately, I need to be able to set the value of the cells specifically, in the order they appear in the ui, even if the columns have been rearranged.

Comment: That makes absolutely no difference. The column values should be data bound to properties of your item class, so to update a value in a particular cell, you just need to update the relevant property on the class instance. Really, you're better off learning how to write WPF correctly. Please see the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information.